# In PoE: is alternative A compatible to all PDs?

Tags: ethernet, poe

I am currently designing a PoE plus device. I'm using 1G speed and currently following alternative A configuration (data pairs 1/2 and 3/6).

Question is: Can all Powered Devices (PD) support alternative A? What happens if I redesign and use alternative B instead? Can PDs still extract power from it? In other words, are PDs compatible with both alternatives A and B?

Also, if I design alternative A only, can the unused center taps be shorted so they share the same surge protection components? I know it's not recommended from a design perspective but I don't have much space on my board!

Answer (score 3):

Devices should assume the powered switches could be using either configuration.  This is usually solved by diodes for each configuration feeding the internal supply.  With the right diodes, the device will receive power either way.

Comment: by devices, you mean the powered devices? So if I'm designing the PSE then I don't have to worry because PDs are supposed to be compatible with either configuration, is that right?